# Pivot column not appear

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I'm currently having problem on PivotTables. It seems that some of the column I created does not appear in Pivot List.

How can I do so?

From `Range("A:AG")` its appear caused by direct copy from original sheet (Let's say `SheetA`). When I copy and add the columns `Range("AI:AO")` (please deny the yellow column) into another sheet `SheetB` the added columns does not appear in Pivot List.

Here the picture of added columns SheetB :

[image: Edited Datasheet]

Meanwhile this is the last List Pivot get :

[image]

How can I solve this?

I do refer [Missing column from table in PivotTable field](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/missing-column-from-table-in-pivot-table-field/4f85a8b5-50c9-45b7-8b5e-b8481984995a) but I think it does not related with this problems.

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub KPIDashboardTable()
Sheets("A").Activate
Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField, Ws As Worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A").Range("A1").Select

Set Ws = Sheets.Add
Ws.Name = "B"

Set objTable = Sheets("A").PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=Ws.Cells(3, "A"))
objTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlmissingItemNone
objTable.PivotCache.Refresh

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("DATE OPENED")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Priority")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField

Dim pf As PivotField
Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("DATE OPENED")
pf.DataRange.Cells(1).Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, _
False, False, True, False, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for mention here, do you know how to solve it @R3uK ? Thanks! TT.TT

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's simple. The error occurs because the `Source Data` **cannot has any gap** (like I did, the yellow one). So if the gap has been removed, try to run the sub again. Then there it is. :)